# How do I use spies for Chai assertion library?

Tags: node.js, typescript, chai, spy

I want to use Chai on a project to test login functionality, here is the login function:

```
public async login(request: Request, response: Response): Promise<Response | any> {
        const staging = request.body.staging;
        const coreUri = (staging) ? 'apiurl' : 'testapiurl';

        const email = request.body.email;
        const password = request.body.password;

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            req({
                uri: `${coreUri}/tokens`,
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                json: {
                    email: email,
                    password: password,
                },
            }, (error, resp, body) => {
                if (error) {
                    return reject(error);
                }

                let statusCode: number;
                let newBody: JsonData = null;
                if (resp.statusCode === 403) {
                    statusCode = 401;
                    newBody = {
                        error: 'Invalid user credentials',
                    };
                } else {
                    if (resp.statusCode === 200) {
                        const roles = (((body || {}).user || {}).roles || []);
                        if (AUTHORIZED_ROLES.some(v => roles.indexOf(v) >= 0)) {
                            statusCode = resp.statusCode;
                            newBody = body;

                            appConfigurationService.setLastAuthorization(body, staging);

                            const token = body.token;
                            HttpServer.saveSessionToken(request, token);

                            logger.info(`User ${email} logged in.`);
                        } else {
                            statusCode = 403;
                            newBody = {
                                error: 'User is not allowed to perform this action',
                            };
                        }
                    } else {
                        statusCode = resp.statusCode;
                        newBody = resp.body;
                    }
                }
```

This is how I've written the test:

```
const spies = require('chai-spies');

chai.use(spies);

describe('API Endpoints tests', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        chai.spy.restore();
    });
    describe('/POST login', () => {
        it('it should login a user and return an object', async () => {
            chai.spy.on(apiController, 'login', () => true);
            const success = await (<any>apiController).login(loginUserDetails);
            console.log(success);
            chai.assert.equal(success, 200);
        });
    });
});
```

But I always get a true on const success, even when I'm passing wrong credentials. I'm sure there's something I'm not getting right, but I don't really know where exactly in the code.

Comment: What is the point of that test? You call the _spy_, there's no real code involved.

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean by "no real code involved"?

Comment: I mean none of your actual implementation is executed in the test. You spy on the method you say you want to test, then call the spy.

Comment: Please at what point do I call the spy? I'm still finding my way around it.

Comment: There aren't that many lines in the test, it should be easy enough to narrow it down.

Comment: But I'm calling the actual implementation here: const success = await (<any>apiController).login(loginUserDetails);

Comment: Do you? Then what do you think the previous line is even doing, and why do you think you always get true?!

Comment: Hmmm...I'm more confused than before posting the question. My understanding was that the previous line is the spy, while the const success line is calling the actual implementation.

Comment: What you should be asking yourself is: if you wanted and were expecting to call actual function, _what did you think the spy was for_.

Comment: Now I understand I'm supposed to spy on the method, then call the method and test against the spy. I thought that was what I was doing....clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: You're _not_ supposed to do that, because it's totally pointless - that's what you're doing in the current test, and that's what's causing the problem. If you spy on the thing you're calling and supply an implementation, all your test can say is that you called the thing you just called and it returned the thing you just told it to. Test doubles are for _collaborators_, don't spy on the thing you're supposed to be testing.